# Using react-router-dom, how can I get the list of children routes from the element?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Say I have something like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='Page' element={<Page />}>
    <Route path='subPage1' element={<subPage1 />} />
    <Route path='subPage2' element={<subPage2 />} />
    <Route path='subPage3' element={<subPage3 />} />
    <Route path='subPage4' element={<subPage4 />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

In the `Page` component, how can have a list of the child route paths?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible for the `Page` component to *know* what nested routes its `Outlet` is rendering? I don't believe it is, but you could pass an array of paths to `Page` as a prop.

Comment: That would be useful too, yes, but mainly I was asking if I could get ['subPage1', subPage2, ...] from the Page component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the routes into the component as a prop like this:

```
const routes = [
  { path: 'subPage1', component: <subPage1 /> },
  ...
];

return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path='Page' element={<Page routes={routes.map(({ path }) => path)} />}>
            {routes.map(({ path, component }) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={component} />}
        </Route>
    </Routes>
);
```

Comment: This is cool, I dont know why I did not think of that!

Comment: This only works so long as none of the components are layout route components (*e.g. render more nested routes*). Slight optmization: change `{ path: 'subPage1', component: <subPage1 /> }` to `{ path: 'subPage1', element: <subPage1 /> }`, then use `{routes.map((route) => <Route key={route.path} {...route} />}`.